# Matching Excel patterns with RegEX

Tags: excel, regex, excel-formula, autohotkey, text-manipulation

I'm trying to make a program (I have been using AutoHotKey) to manipulate Excel formulas to show what's happening.
An example of what I want to do:

- Cell A1: `1`
- Cell A2: `1`
- Cell A3: `=A1+A2` (shown as 2 because 1+1=2)

The code below will manipulate the formula `=A1+A2` into `=ROUND(A1;2)&"+"&ROUND(A2;2)` when this is typed into excel the cell will show `1+1`

The code will add &""& around all math operators `()+-*/` so + becomes &"+"& and - becomes &"-"& and so on.

```
+^c Up::
Send ^c
Clipboard :=  RegExReplace(Clipboard,"[\+\-\*\/\(\)]+","&""$0""$1&")
Clipboard :=  RegExReplace(Clipboard,"&$","")
Clipboard :=  RegExReplace(Clipboard,"\d+\,\d+|(\$\w+\$\d+)|(\$\w+\d+)|(\w+\$\d+)|(\w+\d+)","ROUND($0;2)")
return
```

This works fine for simple formulas like the example above.
The problem is if the formula includes any `IF`, `OR`, `AND` functions.

I think one way to do this is to look at the references instead of the operators.

Like this: https://regex101.com/r/BVPgFH/2

```
(?<=IF\()(.*?)(?=\;(*SKIP)(?!))|\w+\d+
```

The above RegEx will match all numbers and cells like: `A1 1 1337` but not if it is part of the `IF` condition

RegEx for the `OR` function could look like this: https://regex101.com/r/AWRozH/2

```
(?<=OR\()(.*?)(?=\)(*SKIP)(?!))|\w+\d+
```

But as you can see this will not work if the formula only includes an `IF` function, and I'm can't figure out how to combine the two patterns into one.

**I need help combining the two RegEx patterns**

**TL;DR**

I need help creating a RegEx pattern that will match the referred cells in an Excel formula, and at the same time not match the references inside `IF, OR, AND` functions.

The pattern should match `B1, B2, B3, B4` from the formula below because that's part of the evaluated formula and not the `IF` or `OR` functions.

```
=IF(OR(A1=1;A2=2);B1+B2;B3+B4)
```

Comment: So, for clarification, if B1 through B4 contains values 10, 20, 30, and 40, you would want your end result to show as ``IF( OR( A1=1; A2=2 ); 10 + 20; 30 + 40 )``, Right? Or, do you want it to be ``IF( OR( 1=1; 1=2 ); 10 + 20; 30 + 40 )``? (Assuming A1 = 1.)

Comment: The filal goal for the formula is: `=IF(OR(A1=1;A2=2);B1&"+"&B2;B3&"+"&B4)`

Because this will show the value af `B1, B2, B3, B4` I want the cell to show `10+20` and not `30` (Assuming A1=1.)

Comment: Does `\b(?:IF|OR|AND)\([^()]*\)(*SKIP)(?!)|\w+\d` work well enough for you? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mRRtnZ/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew not quiet what I need.
The pattern you made works for the `IF OR` function, but not for the `IF` function alone.

I tried to make an example in word by highlighting what should be matched. I hope it make sense.
https://imgur.com/a/KH5EP4O

Comment: @Mikifp Then try `\b(IF|OR|AND)(?:\((?1))*(\((?:[^()]++|(?2))*\))(*SKIP)(?!)|\w+\d`, see https://regex101.com/r/mRRtnZ/2

Comment: Could you please help finalize this question? Does the above work for you? If yes, I will post as an answer, and the question will be helpful for everyone else. Otherwise, I am not sure what you actually are after and the question is unclear. The sample solution above is an attempt to clear things out, and once you confirm it is good, I will   provide a solution with explanation.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry I've been really busy this last week. It's not it still doesn't match anything in the first line. I begin to think that it's not possible to do with RegEx

Comment: Try 1) `(?:\b(?:OR|AND)(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))|\bIF\((?!(?:OR|AND)\()[^;]*)(*SKIP)(*F)|\w+\d`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/mRRtnZ/3), or 2) `(?:\bIF\((?:OR|AND)(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))|\bIF\((?!(?:OR|AND)\()[^;]*)(*SKIP)(*F)|\w+\d`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/mRRtnZ/4).

Comment: Yes both of them work. thank you